# Como realizar una consulta mysql para reguistrar calificaciones

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin

Buenas tardes estoy iniciando un proyecto donde debo insertar las notas en una tabla dinamica de los cuales tengo las siguientes dificultaldes.

1.- al momento de hacer una colsulta sql con el siguiente codigo me guarda correctamente hasta este punto voy bien.

```
`<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_miperu_alumnos`";
$consulta = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if($consulta->num_rows === 0) {
echo "No hay resultados <br><br><br>";
} else {
?>
`
```

2.- Al momento de poner las condiciones Where NO ME GUARDA al momento de actualizar .

```
``$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_miperu_alumnos` WHERE id_grado=1 ";``
```

Espero su respuesta y ayuda.

[image: Este es mi codigo de consulta en el index]

[image: tabla]

este el archivo proceso para que me actualice
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El detalle esque al momento que Utilizo el  WHERE id_grado='1' and id_seccion ='1'  and id_estado='2' no se guarda ese es mi problema si me pueden ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estas confundido con los tipos de query.

Para Recuperar

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_miperu_alumnos WHERE id_grado=1 ";
// Recupera todo lo del grado con ID 1
```

Para Insertar o Guardar

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tb_miperu_alumnos (nombre) VALUES ('$nombre') ";
```

Para Actualizar

```
$sql = "UPDATE tb_miperu_alumnos SET nombre = '$nombre' WHERE id_grado = 1 ";
```

Para Eliminar

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tb_miperu_alumnos WHERE id_grado = 1 ";
```

Debes averiguar sobre un CRUD...

Comment: Excelente pero el problema sigue